# can asphalt and concrete be laid side by side on roadways?

Tags: concrete, asphalt

Can concrete and asphalt be laid side by side on roadways? If no why? what would be the problems faced?

Comment: Are you asking this for a project you intend to do? If so I recommend you go into more detail than asking a hypothetical with no expectation of intended application.

Comment: The best way to use this Stack Exchange is to lay out your project goal, and your proposed plan of action, then ask a specific question that can attract useful answers to help you achieve that goal.

Comment: @noybman yes m asking this for a project. I have searched through google for this but there was no information neither there was a research paper on this. I have heard from one of my professor that this system is implemented in India and I want to work on this.

Comment: My concept behind this is to lay concrete on the outer edges of the road surface and bitumen in the middle coz on bitumen road often the pits are developed on the outer edges. By placing concrete on the outer edges this can be minimised to some extent as concrete is more durable than bitumen.

Comment: This sounds more like a structural engineering college project than it does something you plan to do in your home's driveway. In that case, I would say this question is off-topic for this stackexchange site.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! The highway department does it all the time.

Comment: True indeed, and they do have problems :)

Comment: WIth the Oblabber stimulus I watched in SF as they tore up a lot of those kinds of problem roads in residential areas, but still replaced them with asphalt for the road and concrete storm drains and curbs.

Comment: Or concrete roadways and asphalt shoulders.